# Does there exist information relating to Eigen::Matrix<> constexpr constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, eigen3

I would like to know if it is possible to *automatically* construct/initialize *at compilation* a static const Eigen::Matrix ? I guess this mandatorily requires a *constexpr* CTOR for all Eigen::Matrix types, among other things. However, I found in the Eigen3 doxy no information about any *constexpr* methods.

Can anybody quote or answer these statement/question ?

Answer (score 7):

Currently, there are no `constexpr` constructors/methods in Eigen. And implementing this would be very complicated (for any non-trivial methods), e.g., because SIMD functions are not `constexpr`.

You can of course initialize `static const` Eigen types, e.g., using assignment:

```
using namespace Eigen;
static const Matrix2d A0 = Matrix2d::Identity();
static const Matrix2d A1 = (Matrix2d() << 1,2,3,4).finished();
static const Matrix2d A2 = [](){ /* some complicated function */
                                 return A0 + A1;
                           }();
```

If you compile expressions like these with optimization, the compiler often will already evaluate these at compile-time (depends on how complicated your calculations are).